# Fast way to find process id by name

Tags: c++, winapi, nt-native-api

Task is: find process id by executable name.
Calling application is 32 bit, finding process can be 32 or 64 bit

Solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")

size_t r_wcsstr(const wchar_t* str, const wchar_t* search)
{
    for (size_t i = wcslen(str) - wcslen(search); i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (wcsstr(str + i, search) != NULL)
            return i + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

bool find_process_1(const std::wstring& name, DWORD& pid)
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024] { 0 };
    DWORD cbNeeded { 0 };
    DWORD cProcesses { 0 };

    unsigned int i;

    if (EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded) == 0)
        return false;

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        WCHAR module_name[MAX_PATH] { 0 };
        HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, aProcesses[i]);

        if (process == NULL || 
            GetProcessImageFileNameW(process, module_name, sizeof(module_name) / sizeof(WCHAR)) == 0)
            continue;

        size_t pos = r_wcsstr(module_name, name.c_str());

        if (pos != -1)
        {
            pid = aProcesses[i];
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool find_process_2(const std::wstring& name, DWORD& pid)
{
    HANDLE snapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PROCESSENTRY32 process_entry = { 0 };
    process_entry.dwSize = sizeof(process_entry);
    bool found = false;

    snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    BOOL success = Process32First(snapshot, &process_entry);
    while (success == TRUE)
    {
        if (_wcsicmp(process_entry.szExeFile, name.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            pid = process_entry.th32ProcessID;
            CloseHandle(snapshot);
            return true;
        }

        success = Process32Next(snapshot, &process_entry);
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return false;
}

int main(int argc, WCHAR **argv)
{
    unsigned long pid { 0 };

    unsigned long long total { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        unsigned long long start = GetTickCount64();

        find_process_1(L"Calculator.exe", pid);

        total += (GetTickCount64() - start);
    }

    std::wcout << L"Total: " << total << L"\tper call: " << total / 1000. << std::endl;

    total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        unsigned long long start = GetTickCount64();

        find_process_2(L"Calculator.exe", pid);

        total += (GetTickCount64() - start);
    }

    std::wcout << L"Total: " << total << L"\tper call: " << total / 1000. << std::endl;

    return 0;

}

Total: 4094     per call: 4.094
Total: 4688     per call: 4.688
```

Is there way faster than `OpenProcesses` + `GetProcessImageFileName` ?

Also i found `QueryFullProcessImageName` function that can slightly decrease find_process_1 time

UPD1: solution with NtQuerySystemInformation 
**Code is wrong see solution**

```
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib")
struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO
{
    ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG                   NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER           Reserved[3];
    LARGE_INTEGER           CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING          ImageName;
    ULONG                   BasePriority;
    HANDLE                  ProcessId;
    HANDLE                  InheritedFromProcessId;
};

bool find_process_3(const std::wstring& name, DWORD& pid)
{
    _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO* spi;
    size_t size = 1024*1024;
    PVOID buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1024 * 1024, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    ULONG real_size {0};

    NTSTATUS ret = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buffer, size, &real_size);

    bool found {false};

    if (NT_SUCCESS(ret) == true)
    {
        spi = (_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO*)buffer;

        while(spi->NextEntryOffset)
        {
            if (spi->ImageName.Buffer != nullptr && _wcsicmp(spi->ImageName.Buffer, name.c_str()) == 0)
            {
                pid = (long)spi->ProcessId;
                found = true;
                break;
            }

            spi = (_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO*)((LPBYTE)spi + spi->NextEntryOffset);
        }
    }

    VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return found;
}
```

and results:

```
Total: 4562     per call: 4.562 // OpenProcess + GetProcessImageFileName
Total: 4453     per call: 4.453 // OpenProcess + QueryFullProcessImageName
Total: 5188     per call: 5.188 // CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
Total: 2797     per call: 2.797 // NtQuerySystemInformation
```

looks really faster, thanks @RbMm

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198689/discussion-on-question-by-goldstar-fast-way-to-find-process-id-by-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for get process id by name need enumerate processes and compare it names with given. how minimum i not listen about ready system api which just do this (and without enumeration internal). of course need understand that do this exist sense primary for system level debug tools - the name of process not reliable. can be many processes with same name, etc.

the fastest low-level way do this - use `NtQuerySystemInformation` function with `SystemProcessInformation` information class. all other ways - based on this api. but have significant overhead and losing info.

the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` - internal call `NtQuerySystemInformation` function with `SystemProcessInformation` but use section ( file mapping on win32 language) as storage for information. copy data tho this section and **unmap** it. the `Process32First` `Process32Next` - all time **map** section to memory again, copy data to your buffer (and **drop** some data in this process) and then **unmap** section. all this serious overhead. of course if you only once do this - you not view different, but if do this many time - different in speed will be visible.

the `EnumProcesses` of course also use `NtQuerySystemInformation` function with `SystemProcessInformation` but from all returned information - pass only process identifier for each process, and **drop** all another info. as result you need call `OpenProcess` and query it image path - again serious overhead and you can not open say protected processes.

of course here i described only current implementation. may be it will changed. may be not. however this is explain why `NtQuerySystemInformation` is fastest.

so documented it or no, "supported" or no - the `NtQuerySystemInformation` is fastest way, if use it correct.

> *may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows*

this is written already 20 years. but still false. i personally sure that this api never will be altered or unavailable (how minimum not early than `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and `EnumProcesses` also will be altered or unavailable) - this is one of fundamental system api. no any reason do this.

> This function has no associated import library. You must use the
>   LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress functions to dynamically link to
>   Ntdll.dll.

this is also **lie**. exist even 2 lib from wdk - *ntdll.lib* and *ntdllp.lib* (here more api but this lib can conflict with crt in some case if you use crt - multiple defined symbols) - so we can, but not need use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` (very interesting for me - how we can call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` without before call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` for get addresses of `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`).

really `NtQuerySystemInformation` usual api function and called as any usual api function. all what we need - declaration for compiler and lib file for linker. lib exist in wdk (and always was here), despite msdn say another

example of usage

```
NTSTATUS GetProcessIdByName(PCUNICODE_STRING ImageName, HANDLE& UniqueProcessId)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x10000;

    UniqueProcessId = 0;

    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PVOID buf = new UCHAR[cb])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                status = STATUS_NOT_FOUND;

                union {
                    PVOID pv;
                    PBYTE pb;
                    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
                };

                pv = buf;
                ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

                do 
                {
                    pb += NextEntryOffset;

                    if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(ImageName, &pspi->ImageName, TRUE))
                    {
                        UniqueProcessId = pspi->UniqueProcessId;
                        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
                        break;
                    }

                } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

            }

            delete [] buf;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```

note that because required buffer size is very volatile (all time new threads created/exited) - need cal this api in loop until we got not `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` status

note `do while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset)` loop - if do while loop - we lost last entry (latest spawned process in system). and ImageName - this is `UNICODE_STRING` - so not mandatory zero terminated. as result use string api which assume 0 terminated string - not correct here (work because in this struct really used 0 terminated string) correct use `RtlEqualUnicodeString` here or similar

also this code search process by name until first match name found. of course need understand that can be multiple processes with same name - for example *svchost.exe*. in real search we can possible use and another conditions, like sessionid, process token properties, command line, etc. this already is separate question and depend from requirements

Comment: You should probably add a note that your solution only finds the first match for `ImageName` - im sure you're aware of that. While this reflects the OPs code, it could hint to a general misunderstanding on the OPs side, that multiple processes might exist that match (some condition that has to be dealt with probably - at least for a function that bears such a generic name).

Comment: @Christian.K i understand it :) question is only about finding and code is example of using different solutions

Comment: @Christian.K - yes, agree. you correct - i search until first match only. i say about *can be many processes with same name* at begin but separate note on code also need